# Read excel data via javascript

Tags: javascript, office-365-developer

I have an .xlsx file that contains information I need to dynamically change a Sharepoint form.

I figured the dynamic portion out myself using Javascript. I can't however seem te open the required file. I did some digging myself and came upon ExcelPlus (which is exactly what I need), but it doesn't work. I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
_getCellCoord 
selectSheet     
openRemote/s.onreadystatechange
```

And

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: *url* does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Any help regarding these errors or other ways of reading the data would be much appreciated.

The code I'm currently using is the following:

```
var ep=new ExcelPlus(null);
    ep.openRemote("*link to sharepoint document.xlsx*", function(passed) {
        if (!passed){
            console.log("Error: impossible to load the remote file");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Data via excelplus:");
            console.log(ep.selectSheet(1).readAll()); // show the content of the first sheet
        }
    });
```

Comment: cross-origin means something is coming from another domain, and the other domain refuses access (which is the default setting for webservers) So you have to enable CORS on that other server

Comment: Both the form from which I try to access the file as the file itself are present on the same sharepoint site. So I don't really see why this error presents itself. The javascript code is present on the following page: .../Lists/5S audits/NewForm.aspx while the document is present here: .../Gedeelde%20%20documenten/auditformulieren/test.xlsx (the dots link to the same sharepoint site).

Comment: Then it could be IFRAME (security) related

Answer (score 0):

You should verify the result of the request that is sent, in the Firefox web console (that is, for me, the best web console to check the ajax requests):
[image: Firefox web console]

You'll see the code returned by the server, and other stuff.

It will show you if the file is correctly retrieved or not. As Danny said in the comments, it looks like there is a cross domain issue (for example https://webA.domain.com and https://webB.domain.com are not the same because the subdomain — webA and webB — are different).

I'm the developer of ExcelPlus. You can also use the [Github issue](https://github.com/Aymkdn/ExcelPlus/issues/) if you need some help.

BTW, I recently found the project [xls-populate](https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate) that looks very nice and easy to use (I didn't try it yet).